# How to show cursor in the middle of the window despite being at the end of the file?

Tags: cursor-movement

I am editing at the bottom of a file, but I want the line I'm editing to appear in the middle of the screen. Is this possible without adding a bunch of spurious newlines at the end of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. Just use `zz` to move current line to the middle of your vim window.

Additionally you can use `ctrl-e` and `ctrl-y` to scroll-up and down.